# Why we should use $().each method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Probably a very basic, but still need to know insite.

For a simple DOM operation, what can force us to use Jquery -> .each ?

Basically, What's the difference between following two?

`$('ul').css('color','black')` AND

```
$('ul').each(function(){ $(this).css('color','black');});
```

What is recommended and why?

Comment: Is it something : one can stop the loop from within the callback function by returning false where as while using $('ul').css, we can't stop the loop through?

Comment: Is this question irrelevant? For me its really good to know should we stay with $().each or use it at only some specific conditions?

Answer (score 3):

`.each` will be useful in situations like this:

```
var a = 100;
$('ul').each(function(){ $(this).css('width',a+'px');  a+=200;});
```

Comment: Can do with `.css`: `var a = -100;
$("ul").css("width", function(){return(a+=200)});`

Answer (score 3):

.each is useful in situations where you want to iterate over each element seperately

```
$( "div" ).each(function( i ) {
if ( this.style.color !== "blue" ) {
  this.style.color = "blue";
} else {
  this.style.color = "";
}
});
```

or

```
$("div").css("color", function(i, val){return val === "blue" ? "" : "blue"});
```

Comment: +1. Conversely, when you don't have complexity like that, don't use each.

Comment: Even for this `.css` is far more elegant `$("div").css("color", function(i, val){return val === "blue" ? "" : "blue"})`

Comment: @Esailija: what do you think is appropriate answer to this query?

Comment: depending upon you level of experience you have to judge which is easier to read.

Answer (score -1):

To iterate over list of objects, you can use $.each(). Very useful if u get a json string or object from ajax call, and then need to iterate over it.

Comment: You are talking about [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) but the question is about [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/). They are not the same thing.